# Bank Account Java GUI

Tags: java, class, user-interface

I need to create a withdraw method for a gui application and no idea how i need to go about it.
So far I have

```java
package ATM;

 Account a1 = new Account(0001, 1000.00, 7.5);
       private void    `enter code here`holderWithdrawActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent    evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:

       double withdrawAmountEntry = Double.parseDouble(holderEntryField.getText());
       a1.setWithdrawAmount(withdrawAmountEntry); 
       Account.withdraw();       
}
```

And this is my account class containing the method.

```java
package ATM;

import java.util.Date;

public class Account {
    private int id;
    private double balance;
    private double annualInterestRate;
    private double withdrawAmount;

    Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate){
        this.id=id;
        this.balance=balance;
        this.annualInterestRate=annualInterestRate;
        this.withdrawAmount= withdrawAmount;
    }

     Account(){
        id = 0001;
        balance = 1000.00;      
     }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the balance
     */
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * @param balance the balance to set
     */
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    /**
     * @return the annualInterestRate
     */
    public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }

    /**
     * @param annualInterestRate the annualInterestRate to set
     */
    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the withdrawAmount
     */
    public double getWithdrawAmount() {
        return withdrawAmount;
    }

    /**
     * @param withdrawAmount the withdrawAmount to set
     */
    public void setWithdrawAmount(double withdrawAmount) {
        this.withdrawAmount = withdrawAmount;
    }
    /**
     * @return the date
     */

    /**
     *
     * @param withdrawAmount
     * @param balance
     * @return the date
     */
    public double withdraw(double withdrawAmount, double balance ){
        return balance - withdrawAmount;

    }  
}
```

Is this the correct way of calling the method? if so why do i have
"method withdraw in class Account cannot be applied to given types;
  required: double,double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length""

Comment: Account.withdraw(); -> 1. withdraw is not a static member, so this won't even compile.
2. withdraw asks for two parameters, and you pass none. This is obviously not the code you got that error message from

Comment: Do you know what event handlers are and how they relate to the operation of your GUI application?